# Как вызвать определённый метод из другого класса?

Tags: c#, .net

Есть два класса. В первом я должен указать какой метод надо выполнить после работы второго класса, а второй, в свою очередь, должен вызвать указанный метод после своей работы.

```
class Program()
{
    Function f = new Function();

    public void main()
    {
        f.doAfter = Program.Method();
        f.doSomething();
    }

    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}

class Function()
{
    public ??? doAfter { get { return DoAfter; } set { DoAfter = value; } }
    private ??? DoAfter;

    public void doSomething()
    {
        //Something doing here
        doafter();
    }

   private void doafter()
   {
       //Здесь должен выполниться метод, указанный в DoAfter, после работы класса
   }
}
```

Это вообще возможно реализовать в C#? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если предполагается хранить методы, которые не принимают аргументов и ничего не возвращают, то будет достаточно `Action`:

```
class Function
{
    public Action doAfter { get { return DoAfter; } set { DoAfter = value; } }
    private Action DoAfter;

    public void doSomething()
    {
        doafter();
    }

    private void doafter()
    {
        DoAfter();
    }
}
```

И использование:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Function f = new Function();
        f.doAfter = Program.Method;
        f.doSomething();
    }

    public static void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! а что если метод предполагает принятие каких либо аргументов?

Comment: @ZecosMAX на здоровье. В этом и проблема. Если метод принимает один аргумент `string`, то должно быть `Action<string>`. Если при этом метод ещё и должен возвращать `string`, то должно быть вообще `Func<string, string>`. Универсальный подход мне неведом. Допускаю возможность, что это из-за моего малого опыта работы с С#, но всё же. Пускаться во все тяжкие и использовать здесь рефлексию - это уже крайний случай. Да и какие тогда аргументы вы будете передавать в метод?

Comment: Discord.MessageEventArgs e, Discord.User User

Comment: @ZecosMAX всё по аналогии: если метод ничего не возвращает и принимает `Discord.MessageEventArgs` и `Discord.User`, то будет `Action<Discord.MessageEventArgs, Discord.User>`.

Comment: и как тогда вызывать DoAfter?

Comment: @ZecosMAX ему, соответственно, нужно передать конкретные объекты классов `Discord.MessageEventArgs` и `Discord.User`. Если эти параметры никак на деле не используются в методе, то можно просто `null` передавать.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!